# hibernate.cfg.xml configuration error

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to run a sample Hibernate program which will insert a values into database, But I am getting below error, where I already included slf4j JAR in my build path please help me fixing this issue.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at org.test1.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:18)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 2 of document  : The document type declaration for root element type "hibernate-configuration" must end with '>'. Nested exception: The document type declaration for root element type "hibernate-configuration" must end with '>'.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty explicit, at some point in the file `hibernate.cfg.xml`, you made a mistake closing one XML tag, possibly a `>` character is missing (perhaps in the element `hibernate-configuration`?). Check the file with a good text editor, it'll help you find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to close the '>' properly it's just a compilation error

Answer (score 0):

You may have not mentioned the doctype in the hibernate.cfg.xml

`<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>`

Use the above syntax, it should work.